# How to minimize filesystem overhead

Tags: filesystems, storage, inode, tuning

I have an application that uses a lot of space as essentially cache data. The more cache available the better the application performs. We're talking hundreds to thousands of TB. The application can regenerate the data on-the-fly if blocks go bad, so my primary goal is to maximize the size available on my filesystem for cache data, and intensely minimize the filesystem overhead.

I'm willing to sacrifice all reliability and flexibility as well as "general-purposeness" requirements. On top of that, I know exactly how many files of cache data I will have on any given volume because the application writes cache files with a fixed size. I'd like to be able to overwrite a file with a new one if a block goes bad occasionally, so it might be good to have a *few* spare inodes lying around, it is also feasible to reformat the entire volume if needed. The files are all stored 1 directory deep in the filesystem. Directory names can be capped at a single letter, for example, and I don't need the directory either (all files could just as well be stored top-level on the root of the volume). Once the cache data is written, the files will only ever be read and the volume can be mounted read-only. The cache is valid for a *long* time (years).

So, given that I know the exact, fixed, file size and have no reliability, checksum, journaling, etc. concerns, what filesystem should I use and how should I go about tuning it to eliminate as much overhead as possible?

Comment: Do the blocks contain compressible data, or are they for all intents and purposes random?

Comment: Within a single file, the data is not redundant and is efficiently packed, so no. Across files there might be redundancies however read performance is somewhat important since this is a cache.

Comment: compression (gz, xz,bzip2...) can sometimes speed up disk read dramatically by compromising CPU and reducing the IO bottleneck.  I wouldn't discount compression just because "it's a cache".  In any case if the data really is read only have you explored squashfs? As a read only filesystem it may have lower overhead but I've never seen it used for that volume of data.

Answer (score 0):

Older file system reference each cluster with a pointer in a page of pointers. Then with 32 bit pointers, you nearly « waste » 4 bytes for each 4 kB : 0.1%. Many people can afford it.

Newer file system use extents, then if you allocate a file with consecutive blocks, you will have a single extent (block from *n* to *m*). Then you will have nearly no overhead. Ext4, Reiserfs, XFS are known to be extent based. But for 100,000 TB, ext4 is too limited. XFS is limited to 8 EB. However, having a single extra large RAID0 may not seem a good idea… perhaps you should have your application handling multiple filesystems.

Comment: I have multiple sets of raid0s for performance. Ext4 works just fine with a 96TB volume. I'm more interested in learning exactly how to tune the filesystem. Perhaps my first step should be to use `xfs` (which I've used in the past) to avoid unnecessary preallocation of inodes and better match my raid striping.